# Is this possible to check if mock being called with one of parameters list

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest.mock

Let's say we have some method:

```
def sleep(self, seconds=0):
    seconds = seconds or self.wait_timer
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

And method-caller:

```
def _sleep_before_next(self, number: int) -> None:
    for counter, wait_timers in self.SLEEPING_RANGES.items():
        if number % counter == 0:
            self.sleep(random.choice(wait_timers))
```

I want to test that `self.sleep` being called with one of `wait_timers`.
So possible options:

First is which I'm using now: patch `random.choice` to always return first element and then use mock's `assert_has_calls`.

```
@mock.patch('random.choice', lambda iterable: iterable[0])
@mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'sleep')
def test_sleep_before_next_calling_time_sleep_with_correct_time(self, mock_time):
    self.my_class_instance._sleep_before_next(30)
    assert mock_time.call_count == 3
    calls = [mock.call(2), mock.call(3), mock.call(10)]
    mock_time.assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=True)
```

Second option is to observe on `random.choice` and see that needed `wait_timers` were passed.
Both of this options required me to mock two objects. So I wander if `unittest.mock` allows to check if one of some params being passed to function to reduce number of mocks, e.g.

```
>>> my_mock(20)
>>> my_mock.time.assert_called_with_one_of(10, 20, 30)
>>> True
```

Comment: I don't think there's a method for that, but you can easily check it yourself with `any` and the [`mock_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow it's actually very helpful comment which gave me an idea how to do this. If you'll write it down as an answer, I'll plus you ;) Thank you sir!